# Does anyone knows a tool to manage internal dev team issues?

Tags: communication

Right now I am part of a team developing a marketplace, and we have a internal problema which we are searching for a tool to solve. Basically what happens is that we often stumbled upon some problems and we end up solving them after a few hours of work, and what we usually do is to share this problem and its solution in a team chat (right now we are using Slack), but turns out that this kind of information is getting lost over time, and because of that, after sometime another person stumbles upon the same problem and does not know that someone else on the team already went through that same problem.

So, we were wondering if there is a tool especifically to solve this problem, some kind of panel for problems and concerns, that we could categorize, organize and filter through the information. We are looking for something simple and direct, that would make easier to share daily basis problems and solutions.

Comment: Take at look to this tool: http://tempo.io/products/tempo-timesheets/
I guess that this can be of value for your requirement. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

2 Possible options are a) a ticketing system & b) a wiki and from the sound of it the wiki is the best bet as you are trying to capture information to be retrieved later.

[MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org) is one of the more common such solutions and allows you to include tags, searchable items, etc. with installation instructions [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installation_guide).

If you don't wish to run your own server then there are a number of online services such as [GitLabs](https://about.gitlab.com/features/) and many others which allow you to host wikis, *plus trackers, source code and even code reviews online in gitlabs* in private restricted access repositories online for reasonable prices.